# SQL Alchemy / Multi Class Realationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a problem.  Looking below, I need the attribute 'priced_item' to be one of 3 different classes.  But with sqlalchemy I only know how to build a relationship to one other class.  How would I build a relationship to multiple classes without using inheritance?  What is the best way to accomplish this?

In the end, I would like to know the best way in sqlalchemy for creating lists containing multiple classes, something trivial in python but tables hit that functionality hard.

Thanks.

```
class QuoteItem(Base, DataObject):
    __tablename__ = 'quote_item'

    uuid = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    quote_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('quote.uuid'))
    quote_template = relationship('Quote')
    position = Column(Integer)
    quantity = Column(Integer)
    priced_item = relationship( ***** HERE IS MY ISSUE *****)

    discriminator = Column('type', String)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'quote_item',
        'polymorphic_on': discriminator
    }

    def __init__(self, quote, quantity, priced_item):
        """

        :type quote: Quote
        :type quantity: int
        :type priced_item: AbstractPart | AbstractLabor | AbstractService
        """

        DataObject.__init__(self)

        self.quote = quote
        self.quantity = quantity

        self.price_item = priced_item
```

Comment: You might find this useful: [Generic Associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is not with sqlalchemy, but actually with the database structure.

Just imagine first, that you only use SQL. How this data can be represented in the database?

The relation between "quoted item" and "priced item" is one-to-many, right? One "quoted item" has many "priced items".

To be able to link them in the database, you will have to create some common table for "priced items", for example:

```
items
-----------
id     type           quoted_item_id
1      priced_type1   1
2      priced_type2   1
3      priced_type3   1
...
```

Each item has a `quoted_item_id`, so each quoted item will have a relation to many priced items.

Then you can have additional tables for different types of priced items (item_id can be the primary key):

```
priced_type_one
---------------
item_id     specific_data1   specific_data2
1           one              two

priced_type_two
---------------
item_id     specific_dataX   specific_dataY
2           55               66
```

And so on.

Above is multiple table inheritance, you can also go with single table inheritance (one big table for all priced items), I think some other variants are also possible.

Once you decide how to do this on the database level, you can move to sqlalchemy and it supports such patterns, check the [Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html) in the docs.